# Ajax Call - simple web service method returns entire page

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I have a simple function in my web service.

```
[Web Method]   
public string TryWB()    
{       
    string sMsg = "try";
    return sMsg;
}
```

and I am calling it from my aspx page. at the top i have tried

```
[ScriptMethod( ResponseFormat= ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

(or .xml or even httpget)

and in the function also I have tried serialising it with

```
sMsg = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(sMsg);
```

or even made custom object just to wrap message, and even tried

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cm,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

From my aspx pages all combinations of text, xml, json made

```
$.ajax({       
    URL: 'FLMSWebService/Login.asmx/TryWB',
    method:"POST", (get also tried)
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                    
    dataType: "text", 
    success: function (data) {                      
        alert('success');                      
        alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
    },                    
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});

contentType: json, xml tried
datatype : xml , json tried...
```

in web.config also

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>      
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule,
            System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
            PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>     
    </modules>
```

and

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <authenticationService enabled="true" />
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

this is all i got from my 2 day search on net...but main point, if i have

```
dataType: "text",
```

its a success and full page returned as data. in every other datatype or content type i get error and the full page is shown in

```
alert(jqXHR.responseText);
```

in the error callback.

I am stuck!! please help

Comment: is it working now

Answer (score 0):

A few changes to try.

change `method` to `type`.

if your service is inside a folder called `FLMSWebService`, add a slash at the front so it looks for the folder from the root.

change dataType to json. asmx returns json by default.

remove `JSON.stringify`, add `data.d`.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: '/FLMSWebService/Login.asmx/TryWB',        
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                    
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (data) {                      
        alert('success');                      
        alert(data.d); 
    },                    
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have created similar replica of your issue and it is work.

Step to debug your issue.

1. check browser console is there any error.
2. check you service URL is it proper else provide complete url and check, example

> url: "http://localhost:50081/FLMSWebService/Login.asmx/HelloWorld"

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowResponse() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/FLMSWebService/Login.asmx/HelloWorld",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
</script>
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time"
    onclick="ShowResponse()" />
```

Login.asmx Service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication1.FLMSWebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Login
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Login : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```